# C++ const correctness with string literals

Tags: c++, constants

According to the C++ standard a string literal type is `array of const char`

```
auto constStr = "aaa";
char* nonConstStr = constStr; //Error here, cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'
char* stillNonConstStr = "aaa"; //Why I don't have error here?
```

Can you please explain me why on the 3rd line I don't get an error?

Comment: @Rapptz I can't seem to find the same a clause allowing the same "backwards-compatibility conversion" in the C++11 standard. I guess it was removed, so the linked question is not really a duplicate nowadays.

Comment: Because it is preferable to allow it as it has been allowed historically than to break thousands of existing programs.

Comment: @Rapptz How is a question+answer about C a duplicate of one about C++? Especially in an area where the two languages actually differ.

Comment: @Angew because they don't differ in this context as much as you think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++03, there was a special rule ([conv.array]§2) which allowed string literals to be converted to type `char*`.

In C++11, this rule no longer exists. In other words, your code is valid C++03, but invalid C++11.

Comment: *illformed* or *deprecated* C++11. Not invalid. This would still compile for historical reasons. [See here without -Wall](http://ideone.com/Itv8Hz) or [here with -Wall -Werror](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bf8d5e2bc40d1220813841a85bfdbe25-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

Comment: @Rapptz: illformed == invalid.

Comment: @Rapptz Beware, *illformed* != *deprecated*, *"deprecated"* things work but are discouraged, *"illformed"* (and *"invalid"*, as *Benjamin* says) things *don't* work.

Answer (score 14):

Historical reasons.  It used to be allowed, and very common, to assign from a string literal to a `char*`, even though the type of a string literal is an array of const char.  I believe it comes from days in `C` where `const` didn't exist, but don't quote me on that.  It was later deprecated, but still allowed so as not to break codebases that used it.  That allowance does not extend to allow `char*` to be initialized from `const char*` (nor from arrays of const char that are not literals), which is why your second line fails.  In C++11, the conversion from string literal to `char*` is banned, but your compiler may not enforce that yet.